# What is a number of distinct Integers?

Tags: number-theory

As i understand is that i for example. { 1, 2, 3,4,4} number of distinct integers are 4. Am I right? And what happens if for example there is big file of data. Do I just get all the numbers then just write out all the numbers that are appearing once and don't write out the second appear of the number for example . 11, 22, 15, 102, 15055, 22, 15. I write out 11, 22, 15, 102 , 15055. And they all together are 5 distinct integers. Or am I completely wrong? Or it is basically the number that doesn't appear twice. For example 1,2,30, 300,30 distinct numbers are 1,2,300 there for there are 3 numbers of distinct integers.

Comment: Your understanding of “distinct” is correct, but it’s not really clear what your question is other than that.

Comment: i have to obtain the numbers or distinct integers. So I try to understand what exactly are distinct integers. The ones that are not the same or just all numbers but counted as one.

Comment: As for "if there is big file of data"... that gets into programming rather than math, but the usual suggestion if you're only dealing with gigabyte or less of data is to make an in-memory JSON object, looping over each of the numbers and for each number $x$ setting the property $x$ of that object to `true`.  Once you are done, you then look at the list of keys for the object and/or the length of said list of keys.

Comment: i need to provide pseudo code so i think of something 
for each line of file do
if number != listnumber
  add number to list
if number == listnumber
  delete number from list

then count all numbers that are in the list = answer

Comment: Your attempt at the pseudocode is rather confusing as to what "listnumber" is... since you are directly comparing to "number" it makes it sound like "listnumber" is just a regular int and that you are only keeping one in memory at a time... doesn't sound like it would work if your file had the numbers appearing in a mixed order rather than in ascending order...  My suggestion again was:  `result = {}; forEach(num in data){res[num] = true}; print(Object.keys(result))` or something like that, adjusting of course for whatever specific language you are working in.

Comment: yes but can you explain exactly what is distinct number and from there I will know what to do? Is it just how many numbers there are for example 1,2,3,4,5,5 is only 5 numbers not 6 because there are two 5s

Comment: I thought we made it clear from the first comment... apparently not.  I interpret "given a list of numbers, construct a new list of all distinct numbers and find its length" to mean that given a list of numbers construct a new list which contains each number that appeared in the original list however only show each number once rather than multiple times in the case that there were duplicates.  So, `[1,2,3,4,5,5]` would become `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: okey thanks a lot now it explains it excellently :) now I know what to do in mapreduce pseudo code :)